# Excel formula to find absolute greatest number in a list compared to another number

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of numbers, let's say:

```
  500        530     460     510
```

Could any one help me with a formula that will look at 530,460 and 510 to find the greatest absolute value differential to 500?

The formula should come up with the answer of 40.

Answer (score 5):

Supposing you have your reference value, `500` in `A1` and all other values below it, use this CSE formula (CSE means you have to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> instead of just <kbd>ENTER</kbd>):

```
=MAX(ABS(A2:A4-A1))
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, thanks bud! I worked on this for hours and couldn't figure it out. Your formula worked perfect!

Comment: @Vince Glad I could help! Would you mind accepting/upvoting the answer if you found it satisfactory?